# Give a min-height:100% to all divs

Tags: css

I've been trying to accomplish this with this

http://jsfiddle.net/madprops/MC47z/

But I can't manage to do it, can somebody help me?

Comment: I am not sure why you have put your html code as an image in your jsfiddle but it is not very helpful. And what are you saying is your problem? You don't know how to set min-width for all divs or it doesn't seem to work when you do? What are you actually trying to achieve with that measurement?

Answer (score 0):

The intended way to make elements inherit properties from others is by relying on "the cascade".  If a parent element has a particular style (height: 100% for example) then its child elements usually (not always) inherit that style.  Sometimes you have to explictly make elements inherit certain styles.

Mention of the cascade in the W3C CSS tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

CSS specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Third-party explanation of the cascade: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/topics/cascade.htm

If setting style on the parent element is forbidden, then you can create a "class".  Style assigned to the class will apply to any element assigned to that class in the document.  So creating a new CSS class does nothing by itself; the document has to assign elements to the class.

W3Schools explanation of classes:  http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Comment: that' why I tried putting height:auto; min-height:100% to everything I could, I don't know what I'm missing. Somebody suggested the problem is display:table but it gets messed up without it.